# Ошибка в переадресации на сайте django django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatc

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

Я уже сделал переход на страничку товара, повторил все так же для странички компании, но получаю ошибку:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'сompany' not found. 
'сompany' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IceCreamHome.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('item/<slug:item_slug>', ShowItem.as_view(), name='item'),
    path('company/<slug:comp_slug>', ShowCompany.as_view(), name='company')
]
```

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name="Производитель")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/company/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name="Фото")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL")
    rating = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Рейтинг производителя", default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('сompany', kwargs={'comp_slug': self.slug})
```

**view.py**

```
class ShowCompany(ListView):
    model = Icecream
    template_name = 'iceCream/company.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'comp_slug'
    context_object_name = 'company'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Компания'
        return context
```

**html шаблон**

```
<a class="company-in-item-block" href="{{ company_obj.get_absolute_url }}">
        <img class="img_company-in-item-block" src="{{company_obj.photo.url}}">
        <div class="company-in-item-block-info">{{ company_obj.name }}</div>
</a>
```

Debug показывает, что ошибка в строчке

```
href="{{ company_obj.get_absolute_url }}"
```

хотя `name`, `photo` и все остальное отлично работает, и если вбить просто ссылку, то страница откроется.

Пожалуйста, укажите на ошибку и покажите пути решения, я новичок в django!